# How to make more secure login system with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make more secure login system with codeigniter. I can make simple one with this example.

http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

But problem here is that with the example I can have direct access to **"check_database"** method from url address. But I want to prevent it. So if user tries to get access to the method he will be redirected to login or welcome page. Please note that I might have more than 10 methods. I don't want to configure them one by one. Do you have any solution?

Comment: So you just want a private method? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private . Actually I think the "private" keyword is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a private function won't work.

If you read the manual you can see you need to write the function with an _ before the function name.

So `function check_database()` becomes `function _check_database()`

read here
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private

Answer (score 1):

Include just after the method opening:

```
if (!$this->input->post())
  redirect('somewherelse!');
```

So if there is nothing as POST request, someone trying to access it directly from URL.

> If might have more than 10 methods...

If all methods should just receive POST requests, then put it on __construct(), something like:

```
function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();

  if (!$this->input->post())
    redirect('somewherelse!');   
}
```

Alternatively you could make a **custom library**, which could have a CodeIgniter reference to use database, and there make all the login business, returning just `true` or `false` on logged status.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Private** Functions. These wont be accessible via URL & will be hidden from public access